# How to get the no. of objects in JSON Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, object, nsarray

If i am saving my data in NSDictionary "dict"

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
```

How can i know that how many objects i am having in seasons, i know how to save NSArray and it's count but it's not an array actually. and all question i saw on stackoverflow they all are using array object.

```
{ "seasons":{  
            "Season 0":{  },
            "Season 1":{  }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSDictionary has a [`count`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDictionary/count) method:

```
NSInteger count = [dict[@"seasons"] count]; // Returns 2
```

Comment: Of course, that assumes that you know that the elements of that dictionary (JSON "object") are themselves objects.

Comment: Yep. Definitely validate your JSON and ensure that `dict` is a dictionary. Validate that `dict[@"seasons"]` is a dictionary or can respond to `count`.

Comment: That wasn't what I was talking about.  A JSON "object" is what translates into an NSDictionary.  If he wants to know how many *objects* (vs arrays or other types) are in the JSON he must somehow determine the types of the elements of "seasons".

Comment: I'm fairly certain the question is simply how to count the number of entries in the dictionary and no more advanced than that.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked.

Comment: Because (duh!) he doesn't know what he's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try This It will give the array of values / keys

```
 [dict allValues]; or  [dict allKeys]
```

Comment: This worked too, NSLog(@"count: %d",(int)[[dictMain allKeys] count]);